# Why is Area51's format so different than any other site?

Tags: discussion, support, area-51, markdown

I was just at Area 51, and noticed that:

- The buttons to access my inbox and sites were on the left side
- The user's box to access the profile is a lot smaller
- When going into the profile, Area 51 focuses directly on reputation

What's going on with Area 51's format? Why is it different than any other site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's old. Really old.

It was always a bit different from the other Stack Exchange sites. And when Stack Exchange revamped their engine, Area 51 was passed over. Changes to Stack Exchange often aren't reflected on Area 51.

Comment: Not just old, it's not a Q&A site, hence can't use the same base design and requires a different codebase.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Calling it "a bit different" was an understatement, wasn't it? I do believe some of the code was shared initially. Haven't found references supporting that though.